# Prevent transition out of current route, but not subroutes?

Tags: ember.js

In certain circumstances I want to prevent user from transitioning out of active route, but at the same time user should be able to transition between sub-routes of current route. I'm can use willTransition event to detect if transition is initiated, but how to detect if transition will exit current route or only transition between subroutes of current route?

The official Ember guide doesn't help in this case.
http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/preventing-and-retrying-transitions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a better way, but you could easily make it work by inspecting the transition object as:

```
Em.Route.extend({

  actions: {
    willTransition: function(transition) {
      var name = this.routeName;

      var isTransitionOut = transition.state.handlerInfos.every(function(item){
        return name !== item.name;
      });

      if (isTransitionOut) {
        alert('aborting');
        transition.abort();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nilac/1/edit

Comment: Thanks, I came up with similar solution myself.

Comment: My only concern is that transition.state.handlerInfos doesn't seem to be public API as it is not documented. But hopefully it will not change without warning:)